# View source code from a "Symbols Server" without debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debug-symbols, symbol-server

I know it's possible to publish our source/symbols to a symbol server, or use something like [SymbolSource.org](http://symbolsource.org) to allow us to step into the code when we are referencing a DLL.

But I have found no way to access this same code when we are not in a debug session.

SymbolSource.org has a demo calculator app that looks like this:

```
var c = new SimpleCalculator();
Console.WriteLine(c.Add(1, 2));
```

When I'm debugging, I can easily step into Add() and see the source code, but when I'm just looking at the code there is no way to do this.

I'm guessing for some reason this isn't possible b/c it would be very helpful and I don't see anyone talking about how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is with [JetBrain's ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It allows you to ctrl+click navigate into sources provided by a symbol server like [SymbolSource](http://www.symbolsource.org) or [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Even though I don't really see a lot of the value with Resharper we ended up buying it just for this navigation feature.  Ill mark this as the answer because it seems to be the only option at this point.

Comment: Hey @chrismay, ping me please if there's anyway I can help for you to get more value out of ReSharper than just symbol navigation. We can offer you among other things a free 3'5 hour course from Pluralsight to see the full potential of the tool. Thanks.